# Express & Passport login request does not close/finish

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to add authentication to my express app using passport, passport-local and passport-jwt. This is what I have for the login code, I have logged the output of the generated token and I try to send it back via the response object, but when I try to login using postman, the request never finished.

```
passport.use('login', localStrategyLogin);
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user._id)
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('login', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return next(new Error("Could not find user"));
        }

        req.login(user, {session: false}, (error) => {
            if (error) return next(error);

            const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id, email: user.email}, JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRES});
            res.send({token});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Login Strategy:

```
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';
import User from "../models/User";

export const localStrategyLogin = new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password'}, async function (email, password, done) {
try {
    const user = await User.findByLogin({email, password});
    if (user) return done(null, user);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}

return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect email or password.'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using `next` instead of sending a response back.

`return next(err);`

> Next is used to pass control to the next middleware function. If not the request will be left hanging or open.

modify it to

`return res.status(500).send(err);`